# Multiple Hide Row Statements in One Worksheet_Change are Overriding Each Other

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide rows based on drop-down selections.

I have two sets of data in the same sheet.
Selection in cell A11 hides either rows 24:36 or rows 12:24
Selection in cell A47 hides either rows 48:51 or row 52.

Both work individually, but when I combine the coding and make the second drop-down selection, it unhides the prior selection criteria.

I want both drop-down selections to work independently, so the sheet doesn't unhide all the other rows.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$11" Then
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case Is = "INDIVIDUAL"
            Range("24:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "4-TIER"
            Range("12:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Else
    End Select
End If

If Target.Address = "$A$47" Then
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Select Case UCase(Target.Value)
        Case Is = "COMPOSITE"
            Range("48:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "AGE-BANDED"
            Range("52:52").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Else
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False` will unhide everything.  No matter the choice it will unhide the other.  Instead limit to the rows you care about: `Range("12:36").EntireRow.Hidden = False` and change the row to the other ones in the second part.

Comment: Just an idea: isn't it good practice to disable events at the start of such an event and re-enable them at the end? Like this, you can avoid having your event handler interrupting itself.

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you!! This worked as well as the answer below.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide/Show Entire Rows

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$11"
            Select Case UCase(CStr(Target.Value))
                ' Note that row 24 will always be hidden (or not)!
                Case "INDIVIDUAL"
                    Me.Rows("12:24").Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows("24:36").Hidden = True
                Case "4-TIER"
                    Me.Rows("24:36").Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows("12:24").Hidden = True
                Case Else ' e.g.:
                    Me.Rows("12:24").Hidden = True
                    Me.Rows("24:36").Hidden = True
            End Select
        Case "$A$47"
            Select Case UCase(CStr(Target.Value))
                Case "AGE-BANDED"
                    Me.Rows("48:51").Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows("52:52").Hidden = True
                Case "COMPOSITE"
                    Me.Rows("52:52").Hidden = False
                    Me.Rows("48:51").Hidden = True
                Case Else ' e.g.:
                    Me.Rows("52:52").Hidden = True
                    Me.Rows("48:51").Hidden = True
            End Select
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```